# Is this A-normal form implementation linear in the size of the AST?

Tags: haskell

In [The Essence of Compiling with Continuations](http://slang.soe.ucsc.edu/cormac/papers/pldi93.pdf) Flanagan et.al. describe a linear time algorithm for converting a term into [A-normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-normal_form). Briefly, A-normal form has all applications only take trivial arguments (e.g. variables) and all non-trivial terms be let bound.

Here's a (silly) example of A-normal form:

```
let x0 = x0 in
let x2 = \ x1 -> x1 in
let x3 = 1 in
x2 x3
```

created from this non-A-normal form term:

```
let y = y in
(\ x0 -> x0) 1
```

I've translated the Scheme code given at the end of the paper (page 11) to the below Haskell module. However, I introduced monads to give me a source of fresh names and to keep a mapping of renamed variables. My question is, is this use of monads destroying the O(n) runtime of the algorithm in the paper? I'm particularly worried about the nesting of `>>=`, which for some monads leads to O(n^2) behavior.

```
-- Based on http://slang.soe.ucsc.edu/cormac/papers/pldi93.pdf
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import Control.Monad.Reader
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M

type Name = String
data Term = Var Name
          | Lam Name Term
          | App Term Term
          | Let Name Term Term
          | Lit Int
           deriving Show

type NameSupply a = ReaderT (M.Map Name Name) (State [Name]) a

fresh :: NameSupply String
fresh = do
    (name:rest) <- get
    put rest
    return name

normalizeTerm :: Term -> NameSupply Term
normalizeTerm m = normalize m return

normalize :: Term -> (Term -> NameSupply Term) -> NameSupply Term
normalize m k = case m of
    Var x       -> do
        mx' <- asks (M.lookup x)
        case mx' of
            Just x' -> k (Var x')
            Nothing -> error $ "var not found: " ++ x
    Lam x body  -> do
        x' <- fresh
        k =<< (Lam x' <$> local (M.insert x x') (normalizeTerm body))
    Let x m1 m2 -> do
        x' <- fresh
        local (M.insert x x') $ normalize m1 (\ n1 -> Let x' n1 <$>  (normalize m2 k))
    App m1 m2   -> normalizeName m1 (\ n1 -> normalizeName m2 (k . App n1))
    (Lit _)     -> k m

normalizeName :: Term -> (Term -> NameSupply Term) -> NameSupply Term
normalizeName m k = normalize m $ \ n -> do
    x <- fresh
    Let x n <$> k (Var x)

run :: Term -> Term
run = flip evalState names . flip runReaderT M.empty . normalizeTerm
  where names = (map (("x" ++) . show) [0..])

example :: Term
example = Let "y" (Var "y") (App (Lam "x0" (Var "x0")) (Lit 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your monad is just `ReaderT ... (State ...)`, and both `ReaderT` and `State` pass single values around, so there's no reason to expect a linear time `(>>=)` or for a O(n) chain to take O(n^2) time.

You can get left-nested quadratic blowups when the monad uses lists or sets or similar.

Comment: Are you sure? Thunks can sometimes form a list like structure that leads to O(n^2) behavior. See for example Oleg's HS14 paper, which talks about snoc lists.

Comment: I'm fairly sure. All the examples, including those in Atze and Oleg's paper (http://homepages.cwi.nl/~ploeg/papers/zseq.pdf) seem to involve multiple values inside the monad in some way or another - e.g. the `Tree` example. And imagine just inlining all the binds with Reader/State - you'd just be left with a bunch of function calls passing values around. I can imagine chains of thunks ending up with blowups if you also applied them at each stage, but I don't think that can be happening here.